# How to send message to whats app group via CHAT-API

Tags: php, chat, whatsapp

I am trying to send a message to a group in whats app with the help of CHAT-API. I was successful in sending a msg to single contact but sending to a group fails miserably.

**CODE FOR API**

```
$arr=json_encode(array(
    "phone"=>"91xxxxxxxx","91xxxxxxxx",

    "body"=>"Test Message CSRGHFGHFGFGHFGH IT Departemnt"
));

$url = "https://eu64.chat-api.com/instance208297/message?token=v59kcnafuz9m8wpe";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ARRAY(
    'Content-type:application/json',
    'Content-length:'.strlen($arr)
));

$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Please help me with sending msg to the group as I am struggling with this from yesterday.

Comment: "miserably" isn't an error message. Please give technical details instead of emotional responses. We might sympathise, but we can't always easily answer the question without more details, unless there happens to be a very obvious flaw in the code.

Comment: It seems there's a private token in your example, I would suggest to never share a piece of code with secrets in it.

Answer (score 0):

"phone" has to be an array, when sending to a group, not like you have written it...

```
"phone" => ['91xxxxxxxx', '91xxxxxx'],
"body" => "Test Message CSRGHFGHFGFGHFGH IT Departemnt"
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a WhatsApp group, you can use the **chatId** parameter, instead of phone parameter.

The value of chatId corresponds to the JID that can be of an individual contact (ending in @c.us) or of a group (ending in @g.us).

The way I find out which is the JID (chatId) corresponding to the group to which I want to send the message, is by entering the chat-api dashboard, and checking the message history.

For example, in my message history:

```
{
"id": "true_56931111111-1547352531@g.us_3EB0D4F45F0136AB1F85",
"body": "*Nueva reserva #1683 desde web* De daniela ......",
"fromMe": true,
"self": 1,
"isForwarded": 0,
"author": "56931111111@c.us",
"time": 1599170329,
"chatId": "56931111111-1547352531@g.us",
"messageNumber": 138,
"type": "chat",
"senderName": "Moloko Reservas",
"quotedMsgBody": null,
"quotedMsgId": null,
"quotedMsgType": null,
"chatName": "Reservas Moloko"
}
```

So there I can see the value of chatId ending in @g.us (56931111111-1547352531@g.us in this example), which corresponds to the group's JID. Then from your code, you simply replace the phone parameter with chatId and enter the corresponding value.

I hope it is useful to you, greetings!